# How to run a python script with dependencies in a virtual environment in Nifi?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-nifi, minify, dataflow, pipenv

Is there a way in Nifi to run a python script which has modules imported from a different folder, requirements specified in a pipfile and has arguments to pass?

In short, how to execute a python script which usually runs in my virtual environment using Nifi?

The end goal for me is to pick up a file using Get File and post it to API. I tried execute process, execute streamcommand processors.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the question -- NiFi has the capability to pick up a file, read the content, and post the content to an API natively. Why is Python necessary for this task?

Comment: are you looking for executeScript processor ?  https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html

Comment: Hi @Andy, yes but I have a bunch of processing left after picking up a file and at the moment it is in python..

Answer (score 2):

To perform follow-on processing on the flowfile using Python, you can use the `ExecuteStreamCommand` or `ExecuteScript`/`InvokeScriptedProcessor` processors.

The [`ExecuteStreamCommand`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html) processor will run an external shell command, like `python3 my_python_script.py -arg1 string -arg2 213`, which can wrap custom Python code and uses `STDIN` to pass the existing flowfile content and `STDOUT` to capture the new flowfile content. Populate the *Command Arguments* and *Command Path* properties of the processor to locate your `python` executable and provide CLI arguments, including flowfile attributes via NiFi Expression Language. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49524039/70465) for an example.

The [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteScript/index.html) processor runs Jython code (Python but without access to native libraries, only Python 2.7 compatibility, and some other restrictions due to JSR-223) in the same JVM as NiFi. You can process the flowfile attributes and content directly with Python code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56081668/70465) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51448062/70465) for more details.

Comment: This only answers half of the question.  If the python script uses a conda virtual environment, is there anything different that needs to happen?  If you are using python's venv, is there anything else you have to do other than point the 'Command Path' at the venv version of python?

Answer (score 0):

Working case.

- I have venv environment previously created through code editor in the `C:\python_nifi_env\.venv` folder
- I have python file with code which imports pandas library named `doing_pandas_thing.py` in the same `C:\python_nifi_env` directory
- In my NiFi UI I created "ExecuteStreamCommand" executor, where

  - Command Path: `c:\python_nifi_env\.venv\Scripts\python.exe`
  - Command Arguments: `C:\python_nifi_env\doing_pandas_thing.py`

And that's all.

```
# doing_pandas_thing.py contents

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1000), columns=['number'])
df.to_csv("C:\\python_nifi_env\\output\\result.csv")
```